# Triggers in Postgresql/postgis

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

I have a shapefile loaded into a postgis database. This shapefile is frequently updated by the source and thus my current process is:

1. Use shp2pgql with -a option to generate insert statements.
2. Run the SQL generated in step 1 to append to database.

Of course, I end up with all the rows from both versions of the shapefile, and what I need is to get rid of all the previous rows and load only the rows from the updated shapefile.

I tried creating a trigger and trigger function in the database:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER drop_all_rows_from_owner_table_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON owner_polygons_common_ownership_layer
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE drop_all_rows_from_owner_table();
```

Here's the trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION drop_all_rows_from_owner_table() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN DELETE FROM owner_polygons_common_ownership_layer;
RETURN NEW;  
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I believe all I have accomplished is to delete all rows from the table, insert the new rows, then delete them again, because when I look at the table after the process ends I have zero rows. I used the FOR EACH STATEMENT clause because shp2sql created one INSERT statement.

My question is: Are triggers the way to go to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger function seems right.

However, I don't think this is the way to go: you cannot be sure that shp2pgsql produces a single statement.
If your shapefile grows, it could split your inserts in multiple statements.

So, if you can't use the -d option (that delete and recreate the table), I'd add a step to the process, between 1 and 2, to truncate the table.

You could also prepend the truncate statement in the generated sql file, or you can execute another psql command to truncate the table.